Why does that screw-propelled vehicle steers opposite to common sense?
Watching videos of screw-propelled vehicles, I came across this one, where at some point (2:15 to 2:40) there's one weird steering/yaw reversal:
While driving forward in a swamp, thrust comes from left screw and right screw isn't spinning. Yet the vehicle steers to the left.
Then left screw is stopped and forward thrust applied to the right screw, yet the vehicle yaws to the right.
how comes it does not turn left between 2:15 and 2:20? It's basically plowing straight forward rectilinear with one screw not spinning at all. that's what i don't get.
I fail to understand that particular behaviour, why does this happen?
for what it's worth, automatic subtitle english translation tells about early development steering issues that's solved only while driving in reverse.
Maybe watching the whole video and not focusing on that particular sequence highlights the nonsensical of that particular sequence.
It shouldn't be able to switch from reverse port thrust to reverse starbord thrust while still happily moving forward as a whole system. Drag should stop it almost instantly

Is that screw reversing?

@WeatherVane yes probably. yet it looks like there's only forward thrust during that particular sequence. ( vehicle moves fwd on a straight path with one screw not spinning, even steering towards opposite direction)

We can't see the the RH screw at that point, but because the craft is turning on a sixpence, suspect that it's in reverse thrust. Like you do in a canoe: you can pull with that paddle, or drag with it.

@WeatherVane how comes it does not turn left between 2:15 and 2:20?

Because the RH screw is in reverse, which slows and spins the craft to the right as you see. You can do this in a rowing boat or canoe.

@WeatherVane so why does it keep its forward velocity? it should at least slow down its pace? (swamp looks like a draggy medium (or water or whatever))

Is there any reason to suspect the vehicle doesn't also have a rudder?

@BowlOfRed no there's no reason for that, and that might be an answer, are you sure it has a rudder? why would it? since it's meant to operate on all terrain

@user721108.  No, I have no information on such vehicles.   If it has a rudder, that could provide enough torque to allow it to pull straight on one screw.

@BowlOfRed I agree

And also, bear in mind the "wagon wheels turning backwards" effect. And from the side, you can't really tell the direction of the craft very well. You'd need to be on it to appreciate its motion.

@WeatherVane well that effect is about those screws percieved direction of rotation, that might be important too, but not related to the whole vehicle's trajectory ( this is water and snow and mud; no illusion lasts that long in those mediums)

@WeatherVane thanks for your helpful insights btw

I think he is counter-steering in order to regain control at that time.

I'm sorry there's something else going one here. This is not akin to one sleek canoe that can still move forward under inertia while counter-rowing on one side. Look at its pitch attitude too. Pitch attitude hints towards thrust direction. And water projection presence or absence discards stroboscopic effect doubts

You ask why it is not turning when the port side screw – the viewer's side – has stopped. But you can't see the starboard screw.

I can only offer some comments, which may or may not be useful. According to the offscreen voice in Russian, initially the vehicle's control was poor, but it improved when they started to use a screw with the "right" helix on the right and a screw with a "left" helix on the left. So I believe that, as a result, the total angular moment when moving forward became zero. If the angular moment is not zero, turning the vehicle to the left or to the right can become tricky due to conservation of the angular momentum.
